# Hibernate error: Method too large (exceeding 65535 bytes size)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, h2

My `@Entity` has 5059 fields (I know... don't tell me), and I am getting the following error when starting my spring boot application with hibernate. My ddl auto is set to "none".

My database of choice is H2, and from what I read [here](http://h2database.com/html/faq.html#size_limit) and [there](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#limits_limitations), it does not have a limitation on the amount of columns. On the other hand, Oracle has a limitation of 1000 columns, and that worries me.

I could certainly post my entity if required, but I can tell you that all fields are of type `CustomString` and `CustomDouble`, that convert to String and Double via `@Converter`.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at com.validator.TranspilerValidatorApp.main(TranspilerValidatorApp.java:10) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:554) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:154) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.load(ByteBuddyState.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.loadProxy(ByteBuddyState.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyHelper.buildProxy(ByteBuddyProxyHelper.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyFactory.postInstantiate(ByteBuddyProxyFactory.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
    Caused by: net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.MethodTooLargeException: Method too large: com/validator/Entity/Bean/EeWmoHigh$HibernateProxy$V6rckrtc.<clinit> ()V
        at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.MethodWriter.computeMethodInfoSize(MethodWriter.java:2084) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(ClassWriter.java:447) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:5171) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1933) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:225) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:198) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3404) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.make(DynamicType.java:3600) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.make(ByteBuddyState.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.make(ByteBuddyState.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.lambda$load$0(ByteBuddyState.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
        ... 57 common frames omitted
```

1. Is my entity so big hibernate cannot handle?
2. How can I do a better tracking of this exception? What should I be looking for?

The exception is thrown when Hibernate checks that a ByteVector's length is bigger than 65535.

EDIT: I have debugged a little bit and noticed that the error is thrown when bytebuddy is constructing hibernate's proxy for my `@Entity`.

[image: debugged]

It seems to me that @Scarabelo is right. Although, its harder to check on the class' length beforehand because hibernate will create it's proxy, which is larger afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is not Hibernate is the limitation of a Java method, because there is an arbitrary hard-coded limit in Java of 64Kb for method sizes. (And actually many other things are limited to 64K, such as method names, the number of constants, etc. See the [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html) specs or the [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) specs for more details.)

Comment: I took at look at it, please help me understand it better: 
The per-class or per-interface constant pool is limited to 65535 entries by the 16-bit constant_pool_count field of the ClassFile structure (§4.1). This acts as an internal limit on the total complexity of a single class or interface.

The number of fields that may be declared by a class or interface is limited to 65535 by the size of the fields_count item of the ClassFile structure (§4.1).

It has never mentioned 65535 bytes size. It refers to it as a count. I could not see any count there that I may be exceeding.

Comment: I think is because every character on a java method has 2 bytes of size, so you only have only 6.4 characters for declare each column, if you exceed that, your method will have more than the limit of bytes

Comment: So when the specification mentions the limit for method name, it is talking about byte size, and not count of methods. The specification is not clear about that...

Comment: This explain a little bit, i took from the documentation: The fact that end_pc is exclusive is a historical mistake in the design of the Java virtual machine: if the Java virtual machine code for a method is exactly 65535 bytes long and ends with an instruction that is 1 byte long, then that instruction cannot be protected by an exception handler. A compiler writer can work around this bug by limiting the maximum size of the generated Java virtual machine code for any method, instance initialization method, or static initializer (the size of any code array) to 65534 bytes.

Comment: So, in this context, is a class considered a method to the JVM? My class is certainly bigger than 65535 bytes...

Comment: This problem is a little frustrating, only 64k per class/method